# Multiple Global Variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript

This isn't a specific problem, but a more theoretical question. Is there ever a good reason to expose *multiple* global variables **for a single Javascript application**?

I can see using, and often use myself, a single global variable to name an object or class containing the app so that it can be recalled multiple times (example below), but I can't think of any case when any additional global variables couldn't be replaced by object properties.

Example where an exposed variable makes life easier (using a closure, it couldn't be recalled):

```
var myGlobalApp = {
    init: function (args) {...},
    methodOne: function () {...},
    methodTwo: function () {...},
    propertyOne: 'string for example'
};
myGlobalApp.init(arg1);
myGlobalApp.init(arg2);
```

Does anyone know of an instance case where multiple global variables would be necessary?

Comment: Maybe for every reusable module that has nothing to with the app? Most prominent example: jQuery.

Comment: That's why I specified in the initial question "for a single Javascript application."

Comment: You mean "*more than one global variable per standalone module*"? Actually I don't see a reason to expose any global variable from your main app routine :-)

Comment: Sure. If we're playing the semantics game then that's what I mean. And the one global variable exposed in the example would be `myGlobalApp`

Comment: How does this feel like to you `APP.domObjects.tables.dataTables.getFirst()` a bit unwieldy? How big is your application and how much are you exposing the global namespace? I'd prefer to break it out into a few objects over one mammoth object. Your call.

Comment: @DavidBarker you just need one global to avoid that: [`define`](http://requirejs.org/) :P

Comment: @Esailija lol, I do actually agree with you, for purposes of this very concise question mind you quoting require.js or modernizr probably wouldnt cut it ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it's ever *strictly necessary* to have multiple globals - JavaScript objects can be arbitrarily nested, and can often be used like namespaces.

```
window.AwesomeModule = {
    app: {
        ...
    },
    util: {
        ...
    }
};
```

In fact, if your app is not made to be reusable (i.e. it's just user-facing), you could probably not leak **any** globals.

```
(function() {
    var AwesomeModule = { ... };
    // Do whatever you want - create DOM nodes, bind to events, etc
    // Just don't bind anything to window
})();
```

A more interesting question is whether having multiple globals would ever be genuinely useful, and I'd say that it depends on your development style. For example, if we look at C# and .NET in general, we can see that the *entire framework* (more or less), namespaces and all, are housed beneath a top level namespace `System`.

Of course, if you're going to be making some huge JavaScript app with multiple components, I would definitely not recommend such a nested structure (besides being possibly unwieldy, JavaScript object attribute lookups have a definite runtime cost, which could add up).

...Regardless, though, the JavaScript landscape is not so well-pruned. A simple check for global attributes yields **around 56 items** on my machine on an *empty page* (running Chrome).

```
var i = 0;
for (var prop in window) {
    if (window.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        i++;
    }
}
```

So, although we can and should minimize our own global usage, the JS environment as it stands today (especially when using external libraries) often involved the proliferation of globals. Example: StackOverflow has around 144 total globals.

Answer (score 0):

Typically libraries for client side Javascript each take at least one global because it would not be cool to *require* the user to use a module library.

0 global variables is a possibility in ES6 with first-class modules.

Comment: So Prototype.js with its many global functions is a notable exception?

Comment: @Bergi what are you implying? My post says that typical library will expose at least one new global

Answer (score 0):

I would say the general rule that applies to Javascript and for that matter any other language is to minimize the case for global variables.  I'm sure there are cases when more than one global variable is necessary but this generally should be avoided as much as possible. When building a library like jQuery you usually only need to expose one point of entry into that libraries functionality.

Also, global variables pollute the Javascript namespace and this could lead to collisions with other people's code.

Comment: "*I'm sure there are cases when more than one global variable is necessary*" -- I would argue that concretely identifying such a case (or generally defining such a class of cases) is the crux of the OP's question.

Comment: Maybe perhaps one case is you're relying on a third party library that is expecting your page to have some global callback into your code.  I'm not suggesting this is a good idea, but if you rely on this third party library, or perhaps it's legacy, then this would be one example but obviously situational.

Answer (score 0):

The only circumstance in which I've exposed multiple globals was for an app that would run multiple instances of itself each of which needed a reference to a single unified resource for use by onclick callbacks.  Even in that case, with a little extra effort I could have kept the resource contained within the app and not needed the extra global.

So in short, on rare occasion it's useful / quick & dirty, but never necessary.

Comment: An onclick callback should indeed use local references only. Polluting the global namespace with handlers really **needs** to be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know of an instance case where multiple global variables would be necessary?

Global variables are **never** necessary, any JavaScript code that uses global variables can be rewritten so that it doesn't.

Even in your example global variables aren't necessary, you can instead use a self-executing function as shown below:

```
(function(arg1, arg2) {
    var init = function (args) {...};
    var methodOne = function () {...};
    var methodTwo = function () {...};
    var propertyOne = 'string for example';

    init(arg1);
    init(arg2);
})(arg1, arg2);
```

Obviously libraries will often expose a global variable for using that library, for example jQuery creates the global variables `jQuery` and `$`.  But for a single JavaScript application, global variables are never necessary.

Comment: What if you needed to invoke some javascript functionality from a mobile application that embeds a webview?  What then?

Comment: @Bergi: True, but if the question is, can it be done without *new* global variables, then the answer is yes (although it isn't pretty). `window.Object.myJSONPHandler = function(d) { ... };` Then have the JSONP call wrapper be `Object.myJSONPHandler`.

Comment: The only problem I see with this implementation is that (in a DOM manipulation type script) it requires either tailoring the script to a specific page, or writing HTML to conform to a script. I prefer the approach of writing a more widely implementable script and calling from inside `<script>...</script>` when and where needed. It seems the best DRY approach in my mind.